# Rails 3.1 Polymorphic Association problem with legacy table

Tags: activerecord, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Let's say I have a legacy MySQL table called `server` with fields `serverid:integer` and 
`servername:string`.

I created a new table called action that will have:

```
t.integer   :actionable_id
t.string    :actionable_type
t.string    :text
```

And I want this table to have a poly relationship with the legacy server 
table.

When I do this:

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "server"
  set_primary_key "serverid"

  has_many :actions, :as => :actionable, :foreign_key => 'serverid'
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :actionable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And I try to get the `Server` for a given `Action`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180-patched :013 > Action.first.actionable
```

I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'server.id' in 'where clause': SELECT 
`server`.* FROM `server`  WHERE `server`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 
'server.id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `server`.* FROM `server`  WHERE 
`server`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
```

How can I make the Action be aware that the primary key is `serverid` 
and not `id`, the same way it is aware that the table name here is 
`server` and not `servers`? Shouldn't it use the set_primary_key value?

Is this a Polymorphic relationship bug?

**EDIT:** After applying the change below (adding primary_key), it works for the Server relation, but I am sure it will fail for the other relations.

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :actionable, :polymorphic => true, :primary_key => 'serverid'
end
```

IMO, the value of primary_key should be automatically recognized by the target's primary_key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kolrie,

We had the same problem at my shop.  Our solution was pretty straight forward.  We simply defined a method that was named the same as the polymorphic relationship. So in your case you would define a method called actionable and do the following:

```
def actionable
  self.actionable_type.constantize.find(self.actionable_id)
end
```

Not sure if that'd work for you, but it's a good work around until the Rails app is fixed to support overriding primary_keys while using polymorphic relationships.